# PHP MySQL Search Combined Columns

Tags: php, mysql, search, sql-like

I had just finished my search functionality for a users system when I found out that it didn't search the way I wanted it to.

If I have a datebase table with 2 columns called 'fname' and 'lname'.

In one row, 'fname' has a value of 'Ashley' and 'lname' has a value of 'Staggs'.

I can search for either 'Ashley' or 'Staggs' and I will get the results correctly, but if I search for 'Ashley Staggs', no results are displayed.

How would I do this properly?

My SELECT query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE fname LIKE '%" . protect($_GET['s']) . "%' OR lname LIKE '%" . protect($_GET['s']) . "%'
```

I knew something like this would happen, but this time I can't figure it out.

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: My [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) sense is tingling.

Comment: @Wiseguy Woops. Thanks for pointing that out. I wrote a function especially for the occasion and forgot to use it.

Comment: Have you tried using `explode()` to separate the search crtieria by a space, and then `trim()` the resulting array? That way, you could divide the criteria into first name and last name.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Ashley Staggs' is neither in fname, nor in lname, so your request doesn't return anything. You could try to concatenate your MySQL fields:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE fname LIKE '%" . $_GET['s'] . "%' OR lname LIKE '%" . $_GET['s'] . "%' OR CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) LIKE '%" . $_GET['s'] . "%'
```

**[EDIT]** Even better:

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
WHERE REPLACE(CONCAT(fname, lname, fname), ' ', '')
LIKE '%" . str_replace(' ', '', protect($_GET['s'])) . "%'
```

Comment: thanks. It worked. Funny thing is I tried CONCAT on another part of the system and just didn't think to use it.

Comment: @Pateman haha. Nope it does not. Then again, i could just do OR CONCAT(lname, ' ', fname) too.

Comment: Nope, this solution isn't very generic.

Comment: Hey, I have another idea, try something like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(fname, lname, fname) LIKE '%" . str_replace(' ', '', $_GET['s']) . "%'`

Comment: Nope, 'cause the str_replace will remove spaces from your GET var. A bit more generic :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fname_lname FROM ( SELECT CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) fname_lname FROM users ) users
WHERE fname_lname LIKE '%" . $_GET['s'] . "%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this - it'll just split the search string by spaces and search for each word:

```
$search = explode(' ', $_GET['s']);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE 0';
foreach ($search as $v)
{
  $v = mysql_real_escape_string($v);
  $query .= " OR (`fname` LIKE '%{$v}%' OR `lname` LIKE '%{$v}%')";
}
// echo $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding sp00m answer, I have a slightly different approach, but built on the same concept.

```
$search = preg_replace ( "/\s\s+/" , " " , $_GET['s']);
```

And then use this query:

```
"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR CONCAT(lname, ' ', fname) LIKE '%" . $search . "%'"
```

**EDIT**

Just had an idea you could use. Basically, you could create two additional fields in the table - `fname_lname` and `lname_fname` , use the regex I mentioned before to get rid of unnecessary spaces, use `explode()` to check the word count. If you have two words, then you can use these two new fields, giving you only two conditions in the query. When you have only one word, you still have two conditions in the query.

Answer (score 0):

hey i want to sugest a stronger more strong search but it required `MyISAM` table
code for this is

```
$q="you search string";
$searchArray = explode(" ", $q);
$query="SELECT * FROM cmusers WHERE  MATCH (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`) AGAINST ('";
$i=0;
foreach ($searchArray as $word) {
$query .= "+".$word."* ";
}
$query .= "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die("Error founded:".mysql_error()."there is problem existing we feels a very great sorry");
$finded=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

working of this can be seen at http://www.funnenjoy.com

Answer (score 0):

I will just do

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) LIKE '%{$search}%'`